# Create newline in Excel cell with enter

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have a cell ("A1" for example), in which you can type, and by pressing enter create a new line in the cell, in stead of finishing the cell and activate the cell below. I don't want to use the combination of Alt+Enter.

I thought doing this by the selectionchange event, and then use application.sendkeys, but i dont really know how. Only if the cell is activated, i want to use the enter-key this way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Likely to be impossible

Comment: You could popup a userform with a textbox which handles input the way that you want and inserts the text into the cell.

Comment: Do you want this behavior for **both** Enter keys or only one of them ??

Answer (score 0):

Sort of similar to John Coleman's idea: You can insert an ActiveX textbox directly into the spreadsheet, make it multi-line with Enter key behavior, and then tie the value of that textbox to a specific cell.

This way, you don't even have to use any VBA.[image: see the setup]

Comment: I knew this one, but thank you. I was just curious if it is possible with just vba.